# Custom routes without resources

Tags: react-admin

I would like to use React-Admin without resources defined but only with custom routes, is it possible?

```
        <Admin title="Panel" basename="/" dashboard={Home} layout={CustomLayout} i18nProvider={i18nProvider}>
            <CustomRoutes>
                <Route path="/documentation" element={<>Documentation</>} />
            </CustomRoutes>
        </Admin>
```

Comment: sure it is possible. My advice: please try it and ask a question here if you have a problem.

Comment: No it is not possible, if no resource is provided there are checks inside React admin that render a status "empty", and with status empty they render the <Ready/> component, the one you can see that asks you to add Resource to Admin

More info => ra-core/src/core/CoreAdminRoutes.tsx line 54

Comment: right, so you'll have to put your custom routes in the Ready component.

Comment: Side question: why do you want to use react-admin without resources?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this with  "react-admin": "^4.5.2".
But i can not reach the custom route.It shows only white page.

my snippet:

```
const Ready = () => (
  <CustomRoutes>
      <Route path={'/contact'} element={<p>Contact</p>} key={'/contact'} />
  </CustomRoutes>
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AdminContext
      store={store}
      dataProvider={dataProvider}
      i18nProvider={defaultI18nProvider}
    >
      <AsyncResources />
    </AdminContext>
  );
};

const AsyncResources = () => {
  const [resources, setResources] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    //empty ressource
    setResources([]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AdminUI ready={Ready} layout={MyLayout}>
      {resources}
    </AdminUI>
  );
};
```